# Cliente socket-io not trigget event "connect" in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

I have an application in Vue and a node server where I connect in real time with *socket-io* 3.1.0, the problem is that the first time I connect to the server from the client, it does not trigger the "connect" event get the *socket.id*. On the other hand, if I update the page, it already works ... I don't understand what happens.

Client vue, main.js:

```
const app = createApp(App)
  .use(IonicVue)
  .use(VueAxios, axios)
  .use(store)
  .use(router);

  app.config.globalProperties.$soketio =  io("https://app.xxxx.net", {
    path: '/stomp',
    secure: true,
    
  });
```

In component:

```
 mounted() {

            this.$soketio.on('connect', (data) => {
                console.log('.....')
            });
}
```

Server:

```
const port = 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Escuchando el puerto: " + port);
});

var path = "/stomp";

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  },
  path: path,
});

global.io = io;
..........
```

Comment: Where is the code for the first time you connect?

Comment: mounted() {

            this.$soketio.on('connect', (data) => {
                console.log('.....')
            });
}

Comment: The first time it doesn't work, but when I reload the page, now the connect event is executed.

Comment: I don't know if it's a push router problem, when I use window.href to go to the page it works ...

Comment: Are you sure `mounted` is running when you expect it to?

Comment: change from mounted to created.  mounted isnt fired every time

Comment: It also doesn't work: 
created() {
            this.abrirCargando('Cargando...', 'my-custom-loading')
            this.$soketio.on('connect', (data) => {
console.log('enter');
            });
           
        },

Comment: try calling socket.connect() twice it worked for me 2nd time use a time out of 100ms